# In kubernetes, how to set different number of pods for different periods of time, such as day and night

Tags: kubernetes

The effect I want to achieve, for example, keep 10 pods running in daytime and keep 5 pods in night, change the number of pod Automatically between day and night.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scheduled scaling is discussed here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/49931.

There are several solutions proposed: CronJob, develop a new controller, ... I would have used a CronJob to update the `replicas` property of the deployments.

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps look at using [kube-downscaler](https://codeberg.org/hjacobs/kube-downscaler).

We use this to scale down deployments after work hours to save on costs. I'm not sure if your purpose is the same but nevertheless it can solve your needs.
It supports flags such as `downscaler/uptime`, `downscaler/downtime` & `downscaler/downtime-replicas` to help you adjust the time when you want to keep a higher (and/or lower) set of pods running and how many pods you want to scale down to. Works just fine for us.